# Assign record approval person based on value on a field

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

Is there a way to assign the approval for a record based on value of another field?
Basically, I was trying to assign the approval based on the "area" field assigned to that record. Based on the area field value, I would like to assign it a user for approval. . But I don't see any options for that when using queue.

I am trying to avoid a trigger / code to manage this as these users should be easily manageable in future without any deployment.

Any help for a solution is much appreciated.

Comment: Worth noting: If you do end up going with a code based route you can build it around custom metadata types. The Custom Metadata itself is editable from the normal setup section in Salesforce. I do this when I need to write a solution programatically, but there is going to be things that get changed on a regular basis. Then you can query the values from the Custom Metadata Type records and perform your logic based off that. That way your logic is hard coded, but the regular changing values won't require constant redeployment.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want code, you can have multiple steps. Each step will have different criteria for records to enter and based on the criteria you can choose the user for that step.

Answer (score -1):

You can always set several Approval Process to specific criteria and assign approver based on that criteria.

[Create an Approval Process with the Standard Wizard](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=approvals_creating_approval_processes.htm&type=5)